# Find sibling of any descendent with matching tag for XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have imported an XML file into my Python script using ElementTree. Now, I want to find any movie or submovie with the "year" tag of "1992" and then I want to print the "rating" value of that movie or submovie. I'm confused about 2 parts of this:
1. Searching for the year tag in ALL descendents, not just immediate children.
2. Returning the rating value once I've searched for a year. Year is a sibling of rating. I'm not sure how to search for one value and return its sibling.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<collection>
    <genre category="Action">
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1981</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>
                'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones 
                is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the 
                Covenant before the Nazis.'
                </description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="True" title="THE KARATE KID">
               <format multiple="Yes">DVD,Online</format>
               <year>1984</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>None provided.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="False" title="Back 2 the Future">
               <format multiple="False">Blu-ray</format>
               <year>1985</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>Marty McFly</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1990s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="X-Men">
               <format multiple="Yes">dvd, digital</format>
               <year>2000</year>
               <rating>PG-13</rating>
               <description>Two mutants come to a private academy for their kind whose resident superhero team must 
               oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="True" title="Batman Returns">
               <format multiple="No">VHS</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>PG13</rating>
               <description>NA.</description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="False" title="Reservoir Dogs">
               <format multiple="No">Online</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>R</rating>
               <description>WhAtEvER I Want!!!?!</description>
               <submovie>
                    <year>1992</year>
                    <rating>R</rating>
                </submovie>
            </movie>
        </decade>    
    </genre>

    <genre category="Thriller">
        <decade years="1970s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="ALIEN">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD</format>
                <year>1979</year>
                <rating>R</rating>
                <description>"""""""""</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Ferris Bueller's Day Off">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1986</year>
                <rating>PG13</rating>
                <description>Funny movie about a funny guy</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="FALSE" title="American Psycho">
                <format multiple="No">blue-ray</format>
                <year>2000</year>
                <rating>Unrated</rating>
                <description>psychopathic Bateman</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
    </genre>

    <genre category="Comedy">
        <decade years="1960s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="Batman: The Movie">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD,VHS</format>
                <year>1966</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>What a joke!</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="2010s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Easy A">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>2010</year>
                <rating>PG--13</rating>
                <description>Emma Stone = Hester Prynne</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="True" title="Dinner for SCHMUCKS">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD,digital,Netflix</format>
                <year>2011</year>
                <rating>Unrated</rating>
                <description>Tim (Rudd) is a rising executive
                 who "succeeds" in finding the perfect guest, 
                 IRS employee Barry (Carell), for his boss' monthly event, 
                 a so-called "dinner for idiots," which offers certain 
                 advantages to the exec who shows up with the biggest buffoon.
                 </description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="Ghostbusters">
                <format multiple="No">Online,VHS</format>
                <year>1984</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>Who ya gonna call?</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1990s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves">
                <format multiple="No">Blu_Ray</format>
                <year>1991</year>
                <rating>Unknown</rating>
                <description>Robin Hood slaying</description>
                <submovie>
                    <year>1992</year>
                    <rating>PG</rating>
                </submovie>
            </movie>
        </decade>
    </genre>
</collection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working example.

Note that the XML doc you have posted was not a valid XML.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''
<collection>
    <genre category="Action">
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1981</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>
                "Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones 
                is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the 
                Covenant before the Nazis."
                </description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="True" title="THE KARATE KID">
               <format multiple="Yes">DVD,Online</format>
               <year>1984</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>None provided.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="False" title="Back 2 the Future">
               <format multiple="False">Blu-ray</format>
               <year>1985</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>Marty McFly</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1990s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="X-Men">
               <format multiple="Yes">dvd, digital</format>
               <year>2000</year>
               <rating>PG-13</rating>
               <description>Two mutants come to a private academy for their kind whose resident superhero team must 
               oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="True" title="Batman Returns">
               <format multiple="No">VHS</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>PG13</rating>
               <description>NA.</description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="False" title="Reservoir Dogs">
               <format multiple="No">Online</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>R</rating>
               <description>WhAtEvER I Want!!!?!</description>
               <submovie>
                    <year>1992</year>
                    <rating>R</rating>
                </submovie>
            </movie>
        </decade>    
    </genre>

    <genre category="Thriller">
        <decade years="1970s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="ALIEN">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD</format>
                <year>1979</year>
                <rating>R</rating>
                <description>"""""""""</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Ferris Bueller's Day Off">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1986</year>
                <rating>PG13</rating>
                <description>Funny movie about a funny guy</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="FALSE" title="American Psycho">
                <format multiple="No">blue-ray</format>
                <year>2000</year>
                <rating>Unrated</rating>
                <description>psychopathic Bateman</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
    </genre>

    <genre category="Comedy">
        <decade years="1960s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="Batman: The Movie">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD,VHS</format>
                <year>1966</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>What a joke!</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="2010s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Easy A">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>2010</year>
                <rating>PG--13</rating>
                <description>Emma Stone = Hester Prynne</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="True" title="Dinner for SCHMUCKS">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD,digital,Netflix</format>
                <year>2011</year>
                <rating>Unrated</rating>
                <description>Tim (Rudd) is a rising executive
                 who "succeeds" in finding the perfect guest, 
                 IRS employee Barry (Carell), for his boss' monthly event, 
                 a so-called "dinner for idiots," which offers certain 
                 advantages to the exec who shows up with the biggest buffoon.
                 </description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="Ghostbusters">
                <format multiple="No">Online,VHS</format>
                <year>1984</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>Who ya gonna call?</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1990s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves">
                <format multiple="No">Blu_Ray</format>
                <year>1991</year>
                <rating>Unknown</rating>
                <description>Robin Hood slaying</description>
                <submovie>
                    <year>1992</year>
                    <rating>PG</rating>
                </submovie>
            </movie>
        </decade>
    </genre>
</collection>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
movies = root.findall('.//movie/[year="1992"]')
submovies = root.findall('.//submovie/[year="1992"]')
print('{} movies were found'.format(len(movies)))
print('{} submovies were found'.format(len(submovies)))

all_movies = list(movies)
all_movies.extend(submovies)
rating = [r.find('./rating').text for r in all_movies]
print('Rating:')
print(rating)
```

output

```
2 movies were found
2 submovies were found
Rating:
['PG13', 'R', 'R', 'PG']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
movienodes_with_year92 = root.findall('.//movie/[year="1992"]')
for mn in movienodes_with_year92:
    rating_nodes = mn.findall('.//rating')
    for rn in rating_nodes:
        print(rn.text)
```

Comment: Does your solution all elements (both "movies" & "submovies") with the year = 1992? Or does it only find the "movies" with the year = 1992?